# Visual Studio Project files and the local Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm starting to use Git and Git Hub with VS2019.  However, i am somewhat confused on how my visual studio solution files are stored and what is stored in the local git repository.

According to this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1RY.png.  there should be two locations on my local PC where my solution files are stored.  In the "Development workspace" which is under c:\Dev<Solution name>  and in the "local Git Repo" which is C:\Users<My UserName>\source\repos.

However, when i create a new solution on my workstation the solution location is defaulting to the Repo location C:\Users<My UserName>\source\repos.

So that is he only location my code is stored.

If i change the locaton for my solution back to  c:\Dev<Solution name> a .git folder is created in this new locaton.  But nothing is created under C:\Users<My UserName>\source\repos.

Is this right or am i missing the point ?
There appears to only be one location for my solution files.

Erick

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a local Git repository and its associated solution files are one and the same - in the same location. The solution files *are* your local copy of the Git repository.

On Visual Studio 16.8.1, you can change the default location of new projects in:

**Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations**.

You can also change the default location of new or cloned Git projects in:

**Git > Settings > Git Global Settings**.